# Google app engine app with custom domain randomly shows 404

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I connected my domain (purchased from NameCheap.com) to a google app engine app, and it started working after few minutes. But sometimes it shows 404, and sometimes just works. It's been like this for 2 days. And it also seem to be showing 404 from different places. My friend in Turkey sees 404 all the time. I verified my domain successfully and I added 4 ip addresses and 4 ipv6 addresses with @ subdomain. and I also set www subdomain ghs.googlehosted.com host. How do I make it work consistently?

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem in your DNS settings, send an email or live chat with Namecheap.com, they will tell you where is the problem.

Comment: there are normally 8 addresses that one needs to set up in order to get the full setup working (4 ipv4 and 4 ipv6)

Also, who is generating the 404 you see? GAE or NameCheap?

Comment: I forgot to mention. I added ipv6 addresses too. GAE is generating 404 page. Well it seems like error is happening when user goes to www.mydomain.com

Comment: I had a similar issue and I found that it went away after about 20 minutes. The 404 is no doubt caused when the request gets sent to a server/data center which isn't yet aware of the new DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this if your authentication domain is set on the application, or if your app.yaml (assuming python) has secure: admin or login: required.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/auth and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs

Answer (score 1):

Try to deploy your code again. It might have been that the code was not successfully deployed to all instances.

Source:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9695